# SQL & PHP HELP!! inserting into 4 tables from 1 form? UPDATE

Tags: php, mysql

Ive now got all of the php and sql working and inserting into all 4 tables correctly but im getting an error of `NOTICE undefined index: product ON LINE 39` but its still inserting into that table? can anyone explain why thats happening?

Heres my PHP code `

```
<?php

    $con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '');

    if(!$con)
    {
        echo'Not connected to Server';
    }

    if(!mysqli_select_db($con, 'horizonphotography'))

    {
        echo'DataBase Not Selected';
    }
/*personal */
    $firstname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['firstname']);
    $lastname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['lastname']);
    $mobile = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['mobile']);
    $homephone = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['homephone']);
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['email']);
/*personal */

/*shipping */
    $region = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['region']);
    $address = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['address']);
    $city = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['city']);
    $postcode = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['postcode']);
/*shipping */

/*creditcard info */
    $nameoncard = $_POST['nameoncard'];
    $ccnumber = $_POST['ccnumber'];
    $month = $_POST['month'];
    $year = $_POST['year'];
    $code = $_POST['code'];
/*credit card info */

/*Product info */
    $product = $_POST['product'];
/*product info */

/*personal */
    $sql1 = "INSERT INTO paymentPersonal (firstname, lastname, mobile, homephone, email) VALUES ('$firstname', '$lastname', '$mobile', '$homephone', '$email')";

/*shipping */
     $sql2 = "INSERT INTO paymentsShipping (address, region, city, postcode) VALUES ('$region', '$address', '$city', '$postcode')";

/*credit card details*/
     $sql3 = "INSERT INTO paymentsPayment (nameoncard, ccnumber, year, month, code) VALUES ('$nameoncard', '$ccnumber', '$month', '$year', '$code')";

/*product details*/
     $sql4 = "INSERT INTO paymentsProduct (product) VALUES ('$product')";


   if(!mysqli_query($con,$sql1)) echo 'Not Inserted into paymentPersonal';
    else if(!mysqli_query($con,$sql2)) echo 'Not Inserted into paymentsShipping';
    else if(!mysqli_query($con,$sql3)) echo 'Not Inserted into paymentsPayment';
    else if(!mysqli_query($con,$sql4)) echo 'Not Inserted into paymentsProduct';
    else echo 'Thank You For Your Order! You Will recive a confirmaton E-Mail Shortly';

    header("refresh:3; url=shop.php");
?>
```

`

and Heres my html `

```
<form action="paymentinput.php" method="post" type> 
        <label>
        <input type="radio" name="product" value="E-turbine" />
            <img src="ETURBINE250.jpg" height="200px" width="200px">
        </label>
        <label>
        <input type="radio" name="product" value="Robocat"/>
            <img src="RoboCat.jpg" height="200px" width="200px">
        </label>
        <label>
        <input type="radio" name="product" value="QuantumVenture"/>
            <img src="Quanum%20Venture.jpg" height="200px" width="200px">
        </label>

        <br>

        </center>
        <div name='paymentform'>
        <h3>Contact/Personal Details ;</h3>
            <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" name="firstname" required>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Last name" name="lastname" required><br><br>
            <input type="int" placeholder="Mobile"name="mobile" required>
            <input type="int" placeholder="Home Phone" name="homephone"><br><br>
            <input type="varchar" placeholder="Email" name="email" required>
            <h3>Shipping Details ;</h3>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Address, 1A Example road" size="35" length=100% name="address" required>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Region, Orewa" size="35" length=100% name="region" required><br><br>
            <select id="city" name="city" title="city">
            <option name="0">City</option>
                <option name="City" value="auckland">Auckland</option>
                <option name="City" value="wellington">Wellington</option>
                <option name="City" value="christurch">Christurch</option>
                <option name="City" value="hamilton">Hamilton</option>
                <option name="City" value="tauranga">Tauranga</option>
                <option name="City" value="hastings">Hastings</option>
                <option name="City" value="napier">Napier</option>
                <option name="City" value="dunedin">Dunedin</option>
                <option name="City" value="palmerstonnorth">Palmerston North</option>
                <option name="City" value="nelson">Nelson</option>
                <option name="City" value="newplymouth">New Plymouth</option>
                <option name="City" value="whangarei">Whangarei</option>
                <option name="City" value="invercargill">Invercargill</option>
                <option name="City" value="whanganui">Whanganui</option>
                <option name="City" value="gisborne">Gisborne</option>
                </select>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Post Code, 0931" name="postcode" required>

            <h3>Billing Information ;</h3>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Name On Card" name="nameoncard" required>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Card Number" name="ccnumber" required><Br><br>
            <select id="exMonth" name="month" title="select a month">
            <option name="month">Enter month</option>
                <option name="month" value="January">January</option>
                <option name="month" value="February">February</option>
                <option name="month" value="March">March</option>
                <option name="month" value="April">April</option>
                <option name="month" value="May">May</option>
                <option name="month" value="June">June</option>
                <option name="month" value="July">July</option>
                <option name="month" value="August">August</option>
                <option name="month" value="September">September</option>
                <option name="month" value="October">October</option>
                <option name="month" value="November">November</option>
                <option name="month" value="December">December</option>
            </select>
            <select id="exYear" name="year" title="select a year">
                <option name="year" value="Enter year">Enter year</option>
                <option name="year" value="2016">2016</option>
                <option name="year" value="2017">2017</option>
                <option name="year" value="2018">2018</option>
                <option name="year" value="2019">2019</option>
                <option name="year" value="2020">2020</option>
                <option name="year" value="2021">2021</option>
                <option name="year" value="2022">2022</option>
                <option name="year" value="2023">2023</option>
                <option name="year" value="2024">2024</option>
                <option name="year" value="2025">2025</option>
                <option name="year" value="2026">2026</option>
                <option name="year" value="2027">2027</option>
                <option name="year" value="2028">2028</option>
                <option name="year" value="2029">2029</option>
                <option name="year" value="2030">2030</option>
                <option name="year" value="2031">2031</option>
            </select><br><br>
            <input type="int" placeholder="Security Code" name="code" required><br><Br>
            <input type="submit" name="Submit"></Br></Br>
            </form>`
```

TIA!

Comment: Don't go live with this! You are not sanitising the user input and putting it straight into SQL queries which opens you up to [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). And, that's not even considering that to save CC numbers, you might need to be [PCI compliant](https://www.pcicomplianceguide.org/pci-faqs-2/#1) to not get yourself into legal trouble.

Comment: just for the use of my school assesment ill be setting up the cc detials but when its ready to go live ill link it to paypal and ditch the credit card :), i wouldnt trust my own coding to process payments etc

Comment: For asessment, I'd still look into [sanitising user input](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) and maybe even [binding the parameters](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php). It will certainly make your code much higher quality.

Comment: ok, will look into it, im currently adding `$firstname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['firstname']);` into the code at the moment to help with the sql injection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your queries are assigned to `$sql`, thus only the last query will be inserted as it will overwrite the previous `$sql`.

You'll need to change them to `$sql1`, `$sql2`, `$sql3`, `$sql4`:

```
/*personal */
    $sql1 = "INSERT INTO paymentPersonal (firstname, lastname, mobile, homephone, email) VALUES ('$firstname', '$lastname', '$mobile', '$homephone', '$email')";

/*shipping */
     $sql2 = "INSERT INTO paymentsShipping (address, region, city, postcode) VALUES ('$region', '$address', '$city', '$postcode')";

/*credit card details*/
       $sql3 = "INSERT INTO paymentsPayment (nameoncard, ccnumber, year, month, code) VALUES ('$nameoncard', '$ccnumber', '$month', '$year', '$code')";

/*product details*/
     $sql4 = "INSERT INTO paymentsProduct (product) VALUES ('$product')";


    if(!mysqli_query($con,$sql1)) echo 'Not Inserted into paymentPersonal';
    else if(!mysqli_query($con,$sql2)) echo 'Not Inserted into paymentsShipping';
    else if(!mysqli_query($con,$sql3)) echo 'Not Inserted into paymentsPayment';
    else if(!mysqli_query($con,$sql4)) echo 'Not Inserted into paymentsProduct';
    else echo 'Thank You For Your Order! You Will recive a confirmaton E-Mail Shortly';
```

This will echo the table name which is not inserted, else it will echo 'Thank You For Your Order! ... '.

**IMPORTANT**: You need to prevent MySQL Injection, e.g. below:

```
$firstname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['firstname']);
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to luweiqi's answer, you will need to execute all four queries ...

```
if(!mysqli_query($con,$sql1) || !mysqli_query($con,$sql2) || !mysqli_query($con,$sql3) || !mysqli_query($con,$sql4))
    {
        echo 'Not Inserted';
    }
```

The problem with this approach is that it displays "Not Inserted" if one or more of the queries fails.  You may want to setup something a bit more granular to check the success/failure of each query and respond to the user accordingly.  But, all that aside, using numbered queries and multiple executes will get the job done.

Comment: awesome thankYou! @luweiqi added more code which worked anyway :)